# bucle iterador for javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Tengo que iterar un numero 5 veces, ya entendi como hacer numeros progresivos, pero un mismo numero no logro entender la formula

hasta aca llegue yo

```
function imprimir5veces5(){

for ( let i = 5 ; i <= 5; i++ ){ 
console.log(i*5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo haz el mismo ciclo for desde `i = 1` hasta `i <= 5` y en cada iteración imprime 5:

```js
function imprimir5veces5(){
  for ( let i = 1 ; i <= 5; i++ ){ 
          console.log(5);
    }
}

imprimir5veces5();
```

Si se va a iterar un número diferente de 5, se puede recibir como parámetro:

```js
function imprimir5vecesN(numero){
  for ( let i = 1 ; i <= 5; i++ ){ 
      console.log(numero);
    }
}

imprimir5vecesN(3);
```

Si se desea que la cantidad de repeticiones y el número sean variables entonces se recibe un parámetro para la cantidad de repeticiones y otro para el número:

```js
function imprimirNvecesM(numero,repeticiones){
     for ( let i = 1 ; i <= repeticiones; i++ ){ 
         console.log(numero);
       }
}

imprimirNvecesM(4,6);
```

Comment: Te doy +1 y elimino mi publicación pues considero que sería solo repetir :)

Comment: `console.log(Array(4).fill(6).join(","))` que tal asi?