# Problema en función llamada imprimir5veces5 que muestra por consola 5 veces el número 5

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucle-for

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El problema es el siguiente:
Definir una función llamada imprimir5veces5 que muestre por consola 5 veces el número 5.

El código que yo realicé fue el siguiente:

```js
function imprimir5veces5() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    console.log(5);
  }
}

imprimir5veces5();
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
>       **La función imprimir5veces5 debe iterar 5 veces**
> ```

Se los agradecería bastante si me pudieran ayudar. Por favor.

Comment: Ese error es imposible, cambia el error a uno existente.

Comment: Tu codigo funciona bien

Comment: cambia `i <= 4` por `i <= 5`

Comment: Si, el código funciona bien y muestra lo deseado, sólo que por más que lo modifico me sigue apareciendo ese error.

Comment: @MarioRivera como digo, ese error es imposible, seguramente te aparece ese "error" es porque estas usando alguna pagina que mira tu codigo y te dice si algo esta mal, algo asi como un reto de programacion o asi.

Comment: @anythingg la condicion del usuario esta bien, ya que si la cambias por `i <= 5` se va a imprimir 6 veces en consola y no 5. igual me parece raro que aparezca el error, porque la funcion hace lo que se especifica que tiene que hacer

Comment: @Riven Así es,es un reto de programación en una pagina y exactamente es como lo describes.

Comment: Esto ya se ha preguntado antes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353642/bucle-iterador-for-javascript

Comment: @MarioRivera recarga la pagina, copia de nuevo el codigo como lo tienes aqui e intenta mirar si sirve.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [bucle iterador for javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353642/bucle-iterador-for-javascript)

Comment: @Riven así es, la pregunta ya fué formulada, y se resolvió para ese caso, pero a mí me sigue apareciendo el error, incluso ya ingresé el código de la otra pregunta.

Comment: Hmmm... haz intentado mirar bien de nuevo la pregunta?, leerla de nuevo detenidamente?, quiza te confundiste y estas en otro ejercicio o talvez la pregunta no era realmente esta, podrias revisar porfavor de nuevo bien la pregunta si dice exactamente esto?

Comment: @Riven ya lo revisé bien, y modifiqué de acuerdo a la publicación que me mencionaban, y me sigue mostrando el mismo error de la imagen

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la página del ejercicio? Toma nota del mensaje acerca de comparadores, tal vez toman en cuenta que el ciclo sea desde cero hasta `< 5`.

Comment: La página en sí no la puedo compartir, ya que para acceder al ejercicio se debe tener una cuenta que ellos mismos generan. Y sí, ya consideré el cambio de comparador.

Comment: También hay una publicación en donde tenían el mismo error,  al final dijo que lo había solucionado, pero que no sabía el porqué, como soy nuevo aquí , comenté preguntándole la solución, pero ocultó mi comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las páginas donde se evalúan ese tipo de ejercicios solo se debe hacer el código que solicitan, en este caso una función llamada `imprimir5veces5()` y eso es todo. La página se encargará de ejecutar la función y evaluar el resultado.

En tu caso luego de declarar la función la estás ejecutando. Entonces la página ejecuta la función y eso produce las primeras 5 impresiones luego se ejecuta de nuevo y eso agrega otras 5 y de ahí el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! Tus consejos me ayudaron a solucionar el error, te agradezco bastante!!!