# Problema con bucles FOR e imprimir consola en Javascript

Tags: javascript

No entiendo cuál es mi error en el siguiente ejercicio:

Realizar una función llamada imprimirAzul4 que muestre por consola 4 veces la palabra Azul.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function imprimirAzul4()
{
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        console.log('Azul')
    }
}
imprimirAzul4()
```

Cuando la ejecuto en la consola me aparece 4 veces azul. Pero me sale un error que dice:

> La ejecución de la función imprimirAzul4 debe iterar 4 veces

No entiendo, se supone que la función hace lo que me piden. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Encontré esta misma pregunta y mencionan que el error sale porque se ejecuta doble o algo así. Pero realmente no entendí, de nuevo gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el erro? Yo lo veo bien

Comment: Hola @WilsonPT el error que me sale es el siguiente:                                           La ejecución de la función imprimirAzul4 debe iterar 4 veces

Comment: @GuadalupeValenzuela ya hay respuesta a esta pregunta, pero fue formulada de manera distinta, pues si buscas aqui mismo en `stackoverflow` una pregunta de imprimir 5 veces su formulacion es exactamente igual a esta y dan el mismo error. de hecho la hicieron hace poquisimo, como unas dos semanas, pero pues... no se habra que buscarla, pero te doy la respuesta corta: el problema es que el reto de programacion que estas haciendo toma como punto de partida el numero 1 y no el cero, es por esto que al hacer el `for` te da ese error, lo otro es que tu condicion debe ser `<=` si comienzas de `1`.

Comment: La pregunta era de hecho tan parecida que lo unico que difiere con esta es que aqui es imprimir 4 veces `Azul` mientras que en la otra es imprimir 5 veces `5`.

Comment: La función está cumpliendo con el objetivo que te solicitan, itera/imprime 4 veces "Azul". La verdad no veo el error.

Comment: La respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/433203/5513 En resumen: elimina la última línea de tu código `imprimirAzul4() ` ese es el error.

Comment: Gracias a todos fue de mucha ayuda sus comentarios. En efecto el error es que volvía a llamar la función --> imprimirAzul4(). De nuevo muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema en función llamada imprimir5veces5 que muestra por consola 5 veces el número 5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/433178/problema-en-funci%c3%b3n-llamada-imprimir5veces5-que-muestra-por-consola-5-veces-el-n)