# Undefined aparece luego de llamar a función

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En un ejercicio me piden que haga una función que imprima en consola 5 veces el contenido de `i`, yo realicé esta función que la ejecuto en una web para probar código y se ejecuta bien `0,1,2,3,4` pero después del 4 me sale un `undefined` y al probarla en la plataforma de donde estoy haciendo el curso me sale error porque dice que `i` debe iterar 5 veces, supongo que debe ser por el `undefined` que me sale después y toma que itera 6 veces. ¿Cómo hago para que no me salga ese `undefined`?

```
function pasitoAPasito (){
for ( let i = 0 ; i <= 4; i++ ){ 
    console.log (i);
 }  
}

console.log(pasitoAPasito())
```

Comment: Creo que si pones `i <= 5` en lugar de `i <= 4` tiene que resultar

Comment: El `undefined` sale porque tu función no tiene valor de retorno, al usarla dentro de un `console.log()`, va a imprimir `undefined`. (No tiene que ver ni con el bucle, ni con el valor de `i`)

Comment: Consejo: aprende a ejecutar tu código _paso a paso_. No hace falta que hagas un `console.log` para llamar a la función.

Comment: Muchas gracais por las respuestas. Si estuve probando y hablando con compañeros y el tema era ese, no hacia falta el console.log() e imprimia el undefined xq la funcion no tenia un parametro. Lo que nos llamo la atencion es que en la plataforma del curso sigue dando error, dice que i tiene q iterar 5 veces, no se que pasa.

Comment: Puedes pasar una imagen de la pregunta que os ponen i de la respuesta?

Comment: como pongo la imagen??

Comment: al editar la respuesta puedes añadir imágenes con el icono del editor de texto.

Comment: ahi subi la imagen

Comment: Pues no veo donde está el error, la verdad, si has escrito el código que te he puesto yo, o el que ha puesto @LuisSalinas, no debería darte el error. Si entendiste el concepto, no te pares, sigue con el curso y reporta el error a los tutores. pd:que curso es? un saludo

Comment: Si ya avise, vamos a ver q pasa. El tema que justo quedamos con un monton de ejercicios para hacer el fin der semana ya que el martes hay examen. El curso de Desarrollador Web Full Stack

Comment: Tu caso es lo mismo que lo que menciona [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/433203), y [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/436684) que también está relacionada a ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te funcione bien deberías llamar al console.log(dentro de la iteración) y desde fuera llamar a la función.

```
function pasitoAPasito (n){
  for ( var i = 1 ; i <= n; i++ ){ 
    console.log(i)
   }  
}

pasitoAPasito(4) //aquí hay que poner 4 si usas <= n o 5 si usas <n,  en la funcion (n), de tal manera que así iterará 5 veces como te piden. Las dos son válidas. Quizá gusta mas usar sin el <=. Por eso da error.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, probando y hablando con compañeros nos dimos cuenta de eso, aunque en la plataforma del curso sigue dando error igual.

Comment: Si puedes pasa una foto de la pregunta y del error que os da. Puede ser que en su sistema de Testing, no le guste que pongas var i = 1 en lugar de 0 o cosas así. ya nos mostrarás. las imagenes si puedes colgarlas. Editando la pregunta. Un saludo y Animo!!!

Comment: Si ejecutas en la consola de un navegador no confundas que al final de los valores mostrados hay un undefine este no tiene que ver con un resultado--> lo aclaro en la  respuesta que publique

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario mandar a llamar a la función dentro de un console.log ya que el **for** esta retornando el valor dentro de el, entonces quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
function pasitoAPasito (){
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ){ 
    console.log(i)
 }  
}

pasitoAPasito()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, probando y hablando con compañeros nos dimos cuenta de eso, aunque en la plataforma del curso sigue dando error igual.

Comment: Chrome/Firefox console.log siempre agrega una línea que dice indefinido

Answer (score 0):

> Tu función no retorna nada por eso solo hace lo que se le pide mostrar
> por consola valores

```
    function pasitoAPasito (){
    for ( let i = 0 ; i <= 4; i++ ){ 
        console.log (i);
// solo muestra los valores no retorna nada
     }  
    }



 > luego se produce algo no querido
```

> porque el parámetro de console.log()
> > externo a  tu función sera undefine

```
    //console.log(pasitoAPasito())->undefine
    entonces  la solución es la que ya te comentaron
    pasitoAPasito()
    Si la funcion retorna un valor entonces en consola no veras undefine
function pasitoAPasito (){
    for ( let i = 0 ; i <= 4; i++ ){ 
        console.log (i);
       
    }
    return 'Termino pasito A Pasito'
    }
    console.log(pasitoAPasito())
/*
node /tmp/1aDXmINqVH.js
0
1
2
3
4
Termino pasito A Pasito
*/
```

[compilador js](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/)

Si ejecutas en la consola de un navegador no confundas que al final de los valores mostrados hay un undefine este no tiene que ver con un resultado

[comportamiento de console.log() en un navegador](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/javascript/chromefirefox-console.log-siempre-agrega-una-linea-que-dice-indefinido/1071382268/)
Chrome/Firefox console.log siempre agrega una línea que dice indefinido